# Export resolved promise result

Tags: node.js, module, promise

Consider I have a.js with following class

```
class Connector {
  constructor (url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.conneciton = null;
  }

  async connect() {
    this.connection = await someThidPartyModule.connect(url);
    return this; 
  }
}

// here I would like to do something like
// export default new Connector().connect();
```

Then use in b.js, c.js etc. connection from resovled connect method:

```
import Connector from 'a.js';

Connector.connection.callSomeMethod(); // here connection already exists after that promise resolved
```

As far as I aware it is not possible to do this, but maybe the some hack or workaround exists?

Comment: What's the point of making `connect()` an `async` method?

Comment: You should never ever `export default` a `new` instance, which is essentially a singleton. If you really wanted to, then you shouldn't have used `class` syntax.

Comment: It is singleton, I did this on purpose

Comment: updated connect method to await thirdPartyModuleConnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some tries found following:

1. export Promise is not a good idea, as on each import we also will get Promise, event if it is already resolved
2. Better to export class instance, call connect method and then allow to use it in all other files
3. Sadly anyway promise moving up to main endpoint file, where we have to make initialization async function and inside wait for promise to resolve

Also tried to export class with static create method, but that leave us with instance on the far end, which cannot be exported to other files.